# Home button disable programmatically

Tags: android, launcher

I'm creating a launcher application.I added some code parts in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But if I pressed home button,then show a message to use which application for default with **Just Once** and **Always** buttons

And also I  tried this code to disable it.but not working.

```
Intent intent10 = new Intent("android.intent.action.touchkey");
                intent10.putExtra("menu_key", "off");
                sendBroadcast(intent10);
```

And I tried to catch the event when press home button,if I catch it ,then please tell me any method to disable that dialog box

thanks in advance

Comment: any update on this as I am also facing the same issue with home button.

Comment: @Gaurav,I couldn't find any solution for this problem